# no margin or padding - but still space between div elements

Tags: html, css, positioning, margin, padding

Its not the first time that this is confusing me.

```
<div id="wrap">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>

#wrap {
width:400px;
height:200px;
background:red;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.content {
width:100px;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
background:green;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

You may get a better understanding when viewing it on JSFiddle

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e86L9/)

For my understanding the four divs should fit exactly inside the parent div,
but there is a space in between them - and i dont understand where its coming from.

would be great if somebody could clear this up for me.

Comment: Just write all your markup on a single line: http://jsfiddle.net/e86L9/4/

Comment: That's so cute :) http://jsfiddle.net/e86L9/3/

Comment: I had to use `white-space: normal` (but maybe because my HTML is generated by a markdown-to-html converter)

Answer (score 25):

This is due to font-size. You will need to set `font-size: 0px` on the #wrap element. http://jsfiddle.net/52eaz/

Comment: i picked this solution - because its the one that makes least sense to me, if any at all. works great though, thanks mate.

Comment: I'd suggest that you select it as the answer for future users.

Comment: The simple reasoning is that CSS property, `letter-spacing`, by default is proportional to the value of `font-size` (which prevents letters [and other inline elements] to bunch up together). Setting `font-size: 0` removes that spacing.

Comment: Hmm, yes, apparently font-size adds a margin. I don't know how you figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/e86L9/12/

```
#wrap {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.content {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;

    background:green;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```